# Application unable to install whenever I add Firebase performance monitoring

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-performance

My application is unable to install whenever I add Firebase performance monitoring. 
It keeps happening even when I uninstall the old app on my test device. Please can someone help me with this? 
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling and existing version of the APK if it is present, and then reinstalling?

Comment: @DougStevenson I did that but it didn't work

Comment: @IloCalistus Can you upload your build.gradle?